# Issue with mysqldump returning Permission denied

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to setup a backup system for MySQL from PHP by using `mysqldump` command but I'm having a *Permission denied error*.
I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6, using system PHP and Homebrew mysql@57.

After many attempts, I could reproduce this issue in Terminal. If I run the command as me, it works fine and the backup file is correctly created, but when I run it as `_www` I get the error.

This works:

```sh
% mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="crd" --extended-insert mydb > backup.sql.gz
```

And this does not work:

```sh
% sudo -u _www mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="crd" --extended-insert mydb > backup.sql.gz
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqldump: Permission denied
```

I checked and `mysqldump` can be executed by user, group and other:

```sh
% ls -la /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin | grep mysqldump                                     
-r-xr-xr-x   1 jbogdani  staff   3853364 Aug 17 21:22 mysqldump
```

Other attempts to provide username and password in the command also fail.

Comment: Why `sudo -u _www`? That's not a real user, it's just for setting permissions.

Comment: your username and password is wrong. double check these please :)

Comment: Can you try to execute using a full path of `mysqldump` like /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqldump via terminal?

Comment: @tadman because I'm getting the error **only** when I try to run the command from PHP via Apache that runs as _www. When I run it from my user no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump will need a password for the mysql user root. If you don't supply that password it won't work, sudo or no sudo.

instead of using `sudo -u _www` just execute it with current mysql user account.

[if you need further reading](https://askubuntu.com/a/378371/890177)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a full path on the output.

You do not have permissions to write to **/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/backup.sql.gz**. Specify full path of the target backup archive to another directory

Comment: I reported here a simplified version of the script, with paths. Destination path and script paths are all correct, and the script is correctly working if run from my user. It is the _www user that is failing.

Comment: Have you tried to specify another path? For example /tmp/backup.tar.gz? The problem is that the user _www have no permissions to write to the current user home directory (/root/backup.tar.gz)

Comment: Actually the dump file is being created, but it is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the _www user is restricted in some way.  It might not have a valid shell, it might be locked, or there might be apparmour/selinux restrictions preventing it from running.

Check the output of dmesg and /var/log/secure for useful logs, otherwise check and change the shell and status of the user using `usermod` to find and isolate the issue.

Make sure you consider the security ramifications before doing anything in production though.

Comment: I guess you are right, but there is not such a log file on my system: `/var/log/secure`. I'm sure that php is using `bin/sh` shell. I also tried to change shell and launched both commands in `sh` (the `mysqldump --def...` and the `sudo -u _www mysqldump --def...`) obtaining same results as above.

Comment: You should be able to find whatever your version of /var/log/secure is with some quick internet searches and your existing knowledge (e.g. what distro you run).  Remember that users need to have a valid default shell to be able to run commands interactively - run 'grep _www /etc/passwd' and see what the last value is to check that.  Run "man passwd", and read about the --status option to learn if it's locked.  There are many things that could be stopping the user from running commands - googling them is easy, the battle is knowing it's an issue in the first place.